# logback.xml class filter configuration need push

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

Ok first of all my logback.xml file:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{25} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>${catalina.base}/logs/server.log</File>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>server.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%d %-5p %C{1} - %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

It's really simple. I have a lot of logs from

```
2015-09-20 15:37:10,013 INFO  o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [adf-context.xml]
2015-09-20 15:37:09,985 INFO  o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from URL ...
```

And I want simply to remove them (filter) I was looking for solution where I found this http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html Everything would be cool but I can't find something that will help me filtering by matching to the class or even word match for **XmlBeanDefinitionReader** Can you push me and help making easy filter for word or class ?